# How many registers does Intel® Core™ i7-3770T Processor have?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I've been looking at this website: http://ark.intel.com/products/65525/Intel-Core-i7-3770T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz

But I can't figure out the number of registers.

Comment: SIMD is an extension to the cpus since the need for sound and graphics just in case u dont know :)

Answer (score 6):

That's kind of an unusual question when evaluating an individual processor, as the number of registers is generally defined at the architectural level.

There are 16 general purpose registers in the x86-64 architecture.  Could you perhaps be more specific as to your question?

[image: x86-64 registers]

Comment: 16 registers per core?

Comment: There are also 16 SIMD registers and 8 x87 registers.  The number of *physical* registers is also different as there are rename registers to support out-of-order execution.

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton: SIMD registers are probably only usable for SIMD instructions. In what sense are "x87 registers" non-general?

Comment: @einpoklum General purpose register is a bit of a misnomer in that most ISAs (m88k being an exception) do not support FP operations in GPRs, but x87 (from what I recall) do not support memory addressing (I do not know how general the integer support was for x87 registers when used as MMX registers). (With respect to SIMD registers, the question asked about registers [I suppose one could also include various others like segment registers and flags and even MSRs.]. SSE/AVX registers support scalar FP operations (I don't know if scalar integer operations are supported.).)

Comment: @einpoklum With the recent addition of gather (and scatter in Xeon Phi, if I remember correctly), SIMD registers can be used for addressing memory directly and it might be less impractical to treat SIMD registers as GPRs, though such would still be very inefficient.

Comment: Then there's the difference between architectural registers (the ones discussed so far here) and the actual hardware registers.

Comment: What about the upper bits? Are there register names for the upper 32-bits for each of these registers?